# Totally trashing and reinstalling Xcode from scratch

Tags: xcode8

I am experimenting a lot of problems with Xcode 8 (both release and beta) and I would like to wipe it out and reinstall it from a clean situation. How do I do it without the installation to find something of the old installation and living it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To absolutely get rid of all **Xcode Caches, Preferences, Supporting Files** etc. you should delete the following files and folders

```
/Applications/Xcode.app
~/Library/Developer/Xcode

/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode 
~/Library/Application Support/Xcode
```

If you also encounter problems with **code signing / provisioning**, you should

1. Reset your login keychain (Keychain Access App -> Keychain Access Menu -> Preferences -> General -> Reset My Default Keychain)
2. Delete `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`